# Which Python GUI framework should I use for this?

Tags: python, text-editor, gui, note-taking

*I'm not sure if my idea is structured well for implementation as an app, I'm walking blind here.

The framework shall handle:

1. editor-like instant color coding of entered text
2. increasingly transparent text lines (as new ones are entered)
3. display data visualization showing counts, averages, time, etc. to find patterns in entries

[image]

Comment: Is this homework? Where do get that requirement, "The framework shall ..."?

Comment: @Mawg Actually the mod rewrote that sentence. It’s just tools/features the idea involves and I’d like to know which framework does those things well.

Comment: @Mawg the mod modified (hence "mod" ) the question from "can X do that" (off-topic) to an on-topic question. Not my area of proficience otherwise, so if you feel something missing, cor certainly will welcome any advice you can give :)

Comment: @Izzy Oh, nothing’s missing. Edit makes sense.